# YouTubeIt "No Method Error" for rater_count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, youtube-api

I'm using YouTubeIt Gem to display some videos and data like # of likes/dislikes/view counts from YouTube API v3 in a Rails app. I'm following a tutorial from http://www.sitepoint.com/youtube-rails/

However, I cannot get certain properties of a video to show after I make the client.video_by(uid) query. Below, I am having trouble getting "rater_count" property (or any others like view_count or comment_count), whenever I do, it throws a No Method Error.

video.rb (my model)

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base

YT_LINK_FORMAT = /\A.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/i
validates :link, presence: true, format: YT_LINK_FORMAT

before_create -> do
  uid = link.match(YT_LINK_FORMAT)
  self.uid = uid[2] if uid && uid[2]

  if self.uid.to_s.length != 11
    self.errors.add(:link, 'is invalid.')
    false
  elsif Video.where(uid: self.uid).any?
    self.errors.add(:link, 'is not unique.')
    false
  else
    get_additional_info
  end
end

private

def get_additional_info
    begin
        client = YouTubeIt::OAuth2Client.new(dev_key: 'AIzaSyCdMoZiea0Z96EhH8cc3No7KJHv2rjey_c')
        video = client.video_by(uid)
        self.title = video.title
        self.duration = parse_duration(video.duration)
        self.author = video.author.name
        self.likes = video.rating.likes
        self.dislikes = video.rating.dislikes
        self.rater_count = video.rating.rater_count
    rescue
        self.title = '' ; self.duration = '00:00:00' ; self.author = '' ; self.likes = 0 ; self.dislikes = 0 ; self.rater_count = 0;  
    end
end

    def parse_duration(d)
        hr = (d / 3600).floor
        min = ((d - (hr * 3600)) / 60).floor
        sec = (d - (hr * 3600) - (min * 60)).floor

        hr = '0' + hr.to_s if hr.to_i < 10
        min = '0' + min.to_s if min.to_i < 10
        sec = '0' + sec.to_s if sec.to_i < 10

        hr.to_s + ':' + min.to_s + ':' + sec.to_s
    end

end
```

Here's my view

```
<% if @videos.any? %>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Latest videos</h1>

    <div id="player-wrapper"></div>

    <% @videos.in_groups_of(3) do |group| %>
      <div class="row">
        <% group.each do |video| %>
          <% if video %>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="yt_video thumbnail">
                <%= image_tag "https://img.youtube.com/vi/#{video.uid}/mqdefault.jpg", alt: video.title,
                              class: 'yt_preview img-rounded', :"data-uid" => video.uid %>
                <div class="caption">
                  <h5><%= video.title %></h5>
                  <p>Author: <b><%= video.author %></b></p>
                  <p>Duration: <b><%= video.duration %></b></p>
                  <p>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> <%= video.likes %>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> <%= video.dislikes %>
                  </p>
                  <p>                   Rater Count: <%= video.rater_count %> </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

the error message

> NoMethodError in Videos#index Showing
>   C:/Users/burea1124/Projects/youtube/app/views/videos/index.html.erb
>   where line #33 raised:
>
> undefined method `rater_count' for # Extracted source
>   (around line #33): 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
>
> ```
>                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span> <%= video.likes %>
>                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down"></span> <%= video.dislikes %>
>                  </p>
>                  <p>                   Rater Count: <%= video.rater_count %> </p>
>                </div>
>              </div>
>            </div>
> ```
>
> Rails.root: C:/Users/burea1124/Projects/youtube
>
> Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
>   app/views/videos/index.html.erb:33:in `block (2 levels) in
>   _app_views_videos_index_html_erb___412445877_32852100' app/views/videos/index.html.erb:19:in`each'
>   app/views/videos/index.html.erb:19:in `block in
>   _app_views_videos_index_html_erb___412445877_32852100' app/views/videos/index.html.erb:17:in`
>   _app_views_videos_index_html_erb___412445877_32852100'

My controller

```
class VideosController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @video = Video.new
    end

    def create
        @video = Video.new(video_params)
        if @video.save
            flash[:success] = 'Video added!'
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def index
        @videos = Video.order('created_at DESC')
    end


private
    def video_params
        params.require(:video).permit(:link)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a rater_count method in your video class, and you can't just access instance variables in ruby.

You can use attr_reader to create an accessor method:

```
class Video < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :rater_count
```

Comment: but video duration, title, author and those fields didn't need attr_reader and could be just read by using self.title = video.title, what is the reason for that?? What's the difference between rater_count and something like title? That's been confusing me -